# Apex to WSDL Generation

Tags: apex, wsdl, wsdl2apex

I have some apex classes generated by WSDL2APEX utility. Is there a way to generate WSDL from the apex class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the methods marked as a web service keyword there will be a link next to the class in the class list to generate the WSDL

Setup -> Develop -> Apex Classes

[image]